# I have just installed 13.04 and am confused buy the security pass-phrase/encryption options

Tags: encryption, passphrase

I included both the security options in my installation. The one was a pass-phrase I chose and the other was a pass phrase generated buy Ubuntu.

What are the each for? I have never had to use the code that was generated, when would I ever need to use it? I am confused.

I now have to enter a code when I turn on and my regular log in. Do I need them both?
Can one be removed and if so what is the best one to deactivate?

Comment: When you say "both security options", which options are these?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/203159/new-encryption-feature-in-ubuntu-12-10-home-encryption-or-full-disk-encryption

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to your user password and the hard disk encryption password.

The first one is required before the encrypted volume is even mounted. If you have encrypted your home (that is, the place where user files reside, your desktop and all), then you need it to access your home directory.

The second is your login password. In Ubuntu, this is necessary not only for logging in, but also for doing administrative tasks (like modifying or updating the system), remotely accessing your machine etc.

If you want to disable one of them, then I'd suggest choosing the option for automatic login. You cannot log in automatically if your home directory does not exist (almost). Go to Settings / User Accounts and set the "Automatic Login" option to "ON".

[image]

You will still need your password for accessing your machine remotely, logging in from a text console or performing administrative tasks (and this is a good thing).

Let me now shortly explain the necessity of having both passwords in general. You see, many Ubuntu machines are servers where many users can log in. Such a machine, if it has encrypted home directories, requires one password at a start-up to mount the home of all the users; then when users log in, they need to enter their respective passwords.

Furthermore, mounting the hard drive partitions is a process that happens usually once at boot time, and is completely independent from the process of user authentication at log in. For example, you can take out the disk with the home directories and attach it to another machine (or a miscreant might do it). Then you can only access the data on the hard disk with your encryption password.

P.S. That said, I don't encrypt my hard disks. I only have a small encrypted directories where I store the really sensitive data.

Comment: I think he means **(1)** the whole disk encryption and **(2)** the home folder encryption, when he says, **"I included both the security options in my installation."**

Comment: Right, this is a change since 12.10. Well, what I wrote still holds I think.

Comment: What you said is right. You need to add a para about the pass-phrase the user is asked to choose for one of the encryption setup. I think it is the **(2)**, but I am not sure. OP does not understand when he may need that pass-phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The generated one will be used when you need to mount to your home folder outside the Operating system or need to recover your home directory...because it has been encrypted. Suppose that your operating system became unstable or broken. How can you get in to the encrypted /home folder to recover your private files?
Of course with the help of the pass phrase that has been generated.