# Full disk encryption vs home folder encryption

Tags: encryption

What is the difference between `home folder encryption` and `full disk encryption` that we find in the Ubuntu versions ?
Which one of them is more secure ?
Using them both could make my laptop more safe ?

Comment: i Found this link, maybe this help you:

[New encryption feature in Ubuntu 12.10: home encryption or full disk encryption? or both?][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/203159/new-encryption-feature-in-ubuntu-12-10-home-encryption-or-full-disk-encryption

Comment: Thank you for the link. It says the full disk encryption is better. But what about using them both : could that be more secure ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, combining the two is safer, but its marginally safer and depends entirely on your passwords. As a regular user, there is no need for the combined, the home folder cant be accessed in any way before the disk is decrypted, using full disk encryption and a strong passphrase will protect your private information sufficiently.